# Pickle version for buildozer spec file

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am creating my kivy apk and i keep running into this error:
**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle==4.0.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pickle==4.0.0**
Originally it was just pickle but then it threw another error so then i changed it to 4.0.0 but still getting the same error

I tried to removed the pickle requirement but the apk will not function if the models are not loaded thus the app crashes.
I would just like to install pickle i suppose through this

Comment: Try uninstalling all versions of pickle and reinstalling 4.0.0

Comment: It wont make a difference when it says there are none versions to get it from